# how to display js 1 time a day?

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a code show popup on the website, I want this popup only show 1 once/day for user.
I use the code below to show the popup:

For functions theme flatsome:

```
    function img_popup(){;?>
    <div class="btn-popup">
    <div class="before-img"></div>
    <div class="img-popup">
        <a href="">
            <img src="link-images">
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php }
add_action('flatsome_footer','img_popup');
```

For js:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        function show_popup(){
            $(".btn-popup").show();
       };
       window.setTimeout( show_popup, 5000 ); // 5 seconds
        $(".btn-popup .before-img").on("click", function(e){
            $(".btn-popup").addClass('hide-imt');
     
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: use a cookie or localStorage to store the last time the popup was displayed to prevent the popup from displaying more than once per day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("lastSet")) {
//  your logic here 
  localStorage.setItem("lastSet", new Date().getTime())
}
```

Comment: you need the check the time whether is a day ago . the above is just a demo